# How do I create a Registry Symlink using Rust?

Tags: windows, rust, registry

I am attempting to create a symlink in my registry, although am unable to figure out how to accomplish it with Rust. I would like to use NtApiDotNet's CreateSymbolicLink function, or something similar. Can someone point me in the right direction on how I would perform this function with Rust?

Comment: I can already create a key and value. But, you are wrong. A registry does have symbolic links. Here is a documentation reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-rrp/d5ce9dcc-1f90-4f5a-b076-cc1d2c9b4195

Comment: I am currently attempting to use the winreg crate and create the RegValue manually... settings it's type to REG_LINK